# I am trying to configure mysql in SpringBoot with mysql but keep getting access denied for user "firstnamelastname" that I cannot even find

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I’m trying to connect mysql to my SpringBoot App but I keep getting the error access denied for user “firstnamelastname.” I can log into mysql using “mysql -u root -p” and “sudo mysql -u root -p”. When I run select user from mysql.user, I cannot find the user I keep getting an error for (“firstnamelastname”). So I cannot even try the set password protocol. Plus my spring.datasource.username in my SpringBoot application.properties isn’t even set to firstnamelastname so I'm not even sure why my application is trying to access SQL through that username.

I uninstalled and reinstalled everything to fix the root username and password previously and thought firstnamelastname would disappear as well but it did not, apparently.
I wanted to try ALTER USER but, as I mentioned earlier, I cannot even find the user in , which is also the user for my MacBook I'm pretty sure (in terminal, the user is the same).